# Now that I have the report viewer working in Local mode, how do I set the default render method?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have finally gotten the ReportViewer to work in Local mode. Now I would like a report to render as a PDF or Excel spreadsheet automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [LocalReport.Render method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839(VS.80).aspx).

I've forgotten exact details but here is a [PDF render](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx) I found